# Matching database with textbox.text

Tags: c#, sql

what i want is to match email and code between textbox and database. If it is matched , the state field will be marked "YES" <----by default empty

the following sample doesn't work anyway..   how can i make a comparing with the database values....

```
          OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sim\Desktop\Web.accdb";
        connection.Open();


         OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        string query = "select * from [Registration]  WHERE [Authentication] = @authentication and [Email] = @email";
        command.CommandText = query;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authentication", TextBox2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox1.Text);
         OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

         if ((reader.Read() == true))
         {
             string query1 = "UPDATE [Registration] SET [State] = 'YES'";
             command.CommandText = query1;

         }

         connection.Close();
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: do you get an exception? what is the exception and what is the inner exception?

Comment: The first reason nothing is happening in your second example, is because after your `select` statement, you are updating the old command's `commandtext`, but not executing it at all.
If you want to do it this way, you will need to iterate over the reader's results, then create and execute a new command for each result.

Answer (score 4):

you could do this with a single query, like so :

```
  using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
  {
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sim\Desktop\Web.accdb";
    connection.Open();


     OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;

    string query = "UPDATE [Registration] SET [State] = 'YES' WHERE [Authentication] = @authentication and [Email] = @email;";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authentication", TextBox2.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox1.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.close();
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much,   but i want to ask if i want to use "if statement"                like if i don't enter correct email and authentication number  , it will occur error messages.... how can i do it?

Comment: You should check those beforehand, with something like `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text)){  /* show an alert box or throw an exception here */  }`